# Wrong jQuery(this) result in a jQuery().parents() foreach loop

Tags: jquery, accordion, parent, css-selectors, nested-lists

I have the following nested `<ul> <li>` menu structure:

```
<ul class="tree-0">
* #<li> 
      <a> Root Category </a>
      <ul class="tree-1">
*        <li>
             <a href="/Home/Products/1">Category 1</a>
             <ul class="tree-2">
*              <li><a href="/Home/Products/11">SubCategory 1.1</a></li>
*              <li><a href="/Home/Products/12">SubCategory 1.2</a></li>
             </ul>
         </li>
  #      <li>
             <a href="/Home/Products/2">Category 2</a>
             <ul class="tree-2">
* #            <li><a href="/Home/Products/21">Category 2.1</a></li>
               <li><a href="/Home/Products/22">Category 2.2</a></li>
             </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I want to select all Category's 2.1 parents of type `<ul>`, untill reach root `ul`. So my code is below:
**URL:** *localhost:22342/Home/Products/21*

```
//Get the `<a>` tag which has the href equal to the pathname
var a = jQuery("a[href='" + window.location.pathname + "']"); //Suppose its Category 2.2

//Get ul parents of <a>  
var parents = jQuery(a).parents("ul");

//Loop through the parents array()
for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
            console.log(jQuery(parents[i]).attr("level")); // check if looping occurs till root
            jQuery(parents[i]).find("li:first").css("background","blue"); // apply a class to first child of the parent element.
        }
```

**THE PROBLEM**:
The blue background is applied to the sections maked with *, but I expect to be marked the sections with #.

Answer (score 2):

Your call `var parents = jQuery(a).parents("ul");` should be `var parents = jQuery(a).closest("ul");`

When you say `var parents = jQuery(a).parents("ul");` it fetches all `ul` elements which are ancestors of the target `a` in this case there are two ancestor `ul` elements, then it applies the css to the first `li` in each `ul` element

If you use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) it will return only the returns the first element matching the selector

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have tryied to make some changes. Now it selects only the first ul after the selected tag <a> but I need to go upper until I reach the root. Still not achieved the goal. Some other ideas?

Comment: @Christian which are the elements you wants in blue background